# arangodb,I can't run the source code

Tags: arangodb

[image]

As shown in figure, each time you run the source code, will enter into this if it, then the program will exit

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless here. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons **not** to post images of code. You've also not explained what you're trying to do or clearly explained the problem you're having, and you've not asked a specific question. When you created your account, you agreed to take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to become familiar with the site. Please do so now, paying special attention to [ask] and [mcve], and then [edit] your question. Thanks.

Comment: Anthony, please open a github issue, describing what you try to do in which environment (including your locale) and whats happening to you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that the ICU locale database wasn't found.

The detailed description on how to set it can be found in [the ArangoDB on Windows Cookbook](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/cookbook/Compiling/Windows30.html#making-the-icu-database-publically-available)